# Which MSBuild target is used for c# code generation?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a custom script that generates C# source files to be included as source files for the library being built. I am currently doing something like this in my `.csproj`:

```xml
<!-- This automatically handles code generation needed by this library -->
<Target Name="codegen" BeforeTargets="GenerateAdditionalSources">
  <Message Text="Running code generators" Importance="high" />
  <Exec command="echo This will be a script that generates .cs files" />
</Target>
```

This calls the script and generates the `.cs` files in a `generated` directory under my project folder, but those files aren't seen by msbuild until the *next* time `dotnet build` is run.

What target should I use to avoid needing to re-run `dotnet build`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670078/how-to-generate-files-during-build-using-msbuild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually want to ask is how to add your newly generated files to the set of files that are passed to the compiler.

Your files need to be added to the `Compile` Item collection.

In your `codegen` target after the `exec` task, add an `Include` of the generated `.cs` files to the `Compile` Item.

Example:

```xml
  <Target Name="codegen" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile">
    <Message Text="Running code generators" Importance="high" />
    <Exec command="echo This will be a script that generates .cs files" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="generated\*.cs" KeepDuplicates="false" />
    </ItemGroup>

  </Target>
```

To be more readable, you might consider using `BeforeCompile` on your target (as in the example).

The `GenerateAdditionalSources` target itself is actually defined with `BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile"`. Using `BeforeCompile` explains your intent that the `codegen` target is performed before compiling.

So that MSBuild can determine if `codegen` needs to be performed you should consider adding `Inputs` and `Outputs` to the target.

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022#BKMK_KeepDuplicates) to documentation on `KeepDuplicates`